# If $A\cup B \in \tau$, then $A,B \in \tau$?

Tags: general-topology

In general topology I've learned that:

> If $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, then of $A,B \in \tau$, then $A\cup B \in \tau$.

I also learned that:

> If $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space and if $A \in \tau$, then $A$ is the union of some sets of $\tau$.

So my question is, if we combine the two propositions can we affirm that:

> If $A\cup B \in \tau$, then $A,B \in \tau$?

Comment: $A = \bigcup \{A\}$ so the second statement you learnt is trivial/void.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely not. In fact, a topology that satisfies this must be discrete. Indeed, let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space with the property that
$$\forall A,B \subseteq X: (A \cup B \in \tau \implies A,B \in \tau)$$

Fix $x \in X$. Then $X= \{x\}\cup X \in \tau$ so we must have $\{x\}\in \tau$ as well. Hence, all singletons are open and thus the topology is discrete, that is $\tau = \mathcal{P}(X)$.

So any non-discrete space is a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

In the usual topology of the real line neither $(-0,1]$ nor $[1,2)$ is open but their union is open.